# Drag from NSTableView to Finder, get destination path?

Tags: cocoa, drag-and-drop, finder

I have an NSTableView containing representations of files. I am able to drag these to the Finder with NSDragOperationMove or NSDragOperationCopy and it works fine. The files are correctly moved (even across volumes) or copied.

When dragging with NSDragOperationMove, I'd like to know the parent folder of where the files were dropped in Finder so I can update the paths/bookmarks of the representations I keep internally.

How can I get Finder to tell me where the files were dropped?

Comment: How do you put the files on the pastboard?

Comment: -(BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)inTableView writeRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pboard, using  [pboard setPropertyList:files forType:NSFilenamesPboardType];

Comment: Can you move a file to a different volume? Can you update a bookmark if the file stays on the same volume?